# Unopened wine bottles kept in fridge. Are they still good?

Tags: food-preservation, refrigerator, alcohol, wine

I have a couple of bottles of wine in my fridge that have never been opened (original packaging) and have been there for ~3 years.
Would that mean that the wine have become worse and hence should dispose of the bottles?
Or does it mean the wine has "matured" and is even better?
Was keeping them in the fridge a good choice?

Comment: Are they cork, plastic or screw-top? Laid down or upright?

Comment: @Tetsujin: Cork and laid down

Comment: We need to know more about the wine. Red or white? Sweet or dry? What grape?

Answer (score 3):

It depends on the wine. A bit cold for standard "cellaring" of wine, and some wine matures well, while other wines are short-lived.

It should not be dangerous, anyway.

You can taste it and decide for yourself which way it went, if any. At which point you'll need to drink or dispose in a relatively short timeframe, as it will no longer be sealed (though things like a vacuum stopper can help maintain quality for a while.)

Sometimes "not so good for drinking" is "fine to cook a stew or marinate with." so don't jump to dumping it unless it's truly awful.

Comment: 1) I should not have kept it in the fridge? 2) If it is short lived would it have some expiration date?

Comment: Most wines should be "cellared" between 45-55 °F so a typical fridge is colder than is ideal. Expiration dates would be highly unusual. But something like "Beaujolais Nouveau" is intended to be drunk young, for instance.

Comment: So if stored at around 55 F (~12 C) can they be preserved for a long time? What about those wines we see on TV where people say X years ago wine?

Comment: They are presumed to have been stored in a cellar, often a literal one, or a cave, where the ground temperature at sufficient depth is consistent and in the proper range.

Comment: So in room temperature at a house, for how long time an unopened bottle of wine should be kept and still taste good? Also is keeping the bottle in the fridge always a bad idea?

Comment: The other issue with storing them in the fridge happens if they have corks and they're stored upright.  The corks can dry out, letting air into the bottle.